# Need javascript checking zipcode for hawaii alaska, etc

Tags: javascript

Is there an easy way to do something (in javascript) depending on the zipcode?
To be more precise, a user would enter in a zipcode and if that zipcode is outside of the continental usa (like hawaii, alaska, puerto rico, etc.) then it would do something like hide the free shipping option. I know this can easily be done with the state field, but how about the zipcode field?

Comment: Do you have a database of zipcodes to look up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set of all zip codes for locations in the continental U.S. (excluding of course Alaska, Hawaii, and U.S. territories) can be defined as follows:

Zip code is greater than 00999 but less than 96200

OR

Zip code is equal to or greater than 97000 but less than 99500

```
function isInContinentalUSA(zipcode)
{
    if((zipcode>'00999' && zipcode <'96200') || (zipcode>='97000' && zipcode <'99500')) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Outlying US territories follow these rules so I updated code above to manage Puerto Rico

```
US Outlying territories
AP: 962** - 966**
PW/FM/MH/MP/GU: 969**
AS: 96799
PR: 006-009
```

Appropriated from Addoa: http://addoa.com/blog/how-restrict-free-shipping-magento

Comment: Actually.. I found 00988 as a zipcode for Puerto Rico.. so it would be more than that number.

Answer (score 1):

The USPS provides a free API for getting location information from a zip code. See https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/address-information.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need some list on the client side to tell if the zip code is allowed.

Or you need to ping a server to check if the zip code fits your given parameters.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/hi/ shows that Hawaii ZIP codes start with 967 and 968.
http://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/ak/ shows that Alaska ZIP codes start with 995, 996, 997, 998 and 999.

So, you want something like this:

```
// var zipCodeStr
var notContinental = zipCodeStr.match(/^(967|968|995|996|997|998|999)/);
```

**EDIT**

megawc brings up the good point that if I wanted to be most efficient, I should've used `test`, not `match`.  So I would recommend this code:

```
var notContinental = /^(967|968|995|996|997|998|999)/.test(zipCodeStr);
```

Also, I noticed that my previous regex was missing 998 and 999, so I added them in.

Comment: Think you should change that to `/^(96[7-8]|99[5-7])\d{2}$/`

Comment: @megawac I didn't figure I was validating a ZIP code, just checking it.  I could also handle the ZIP+4: `/^(967|968|995|996|997)\d{2}(-\d{5})?/`, but I'm just testing for AK or HI.  Validation is an entirely different issue, and I could make a good case that it should be a *separate* issue as well.  (Validation shouldn't be combined with business logic, in my opinion.)

Comment: I figured because you were using match you wanted to find the zipcode if its non continental and not just the start of the code

Comment: @megawac Ah!  I see your point.  You're right, I should've just used regex.test.  I'll update.

Comment: This is not a problem suited to regex. IT is more easily handled with simple string comparison which makes it both more readable and likely faster due to the short circuit nature of the eval.

Comment: @Emmentaler The fact that you find conditionals more aesthetically pleasing does not imply that this problem is not suited to regex.  You're searching a string to see if it contains certain substrings - that makes regex a decent candidate.  In this case, we're searching for 3 characters at the beginning of the string, so the regex will be fast.  I happen to find my version to be clear and concise.  Neither you nor I have bothered putting it to a test to see which is faster, so shouldn't make unsubstantiated claims as to performance.

Comment: I confess, a common argument that has no obvious answer and in this case it is most likely irrelevant as the question doesn't seem to indicate that speed is an issue.

Comment: @Emmentaler It's official, your way is about twice as fast.  http://jsperf.com/zip-code-checking-integer-comparison-vs-regex  I'll hide behind the fact that OP didn't care about performance. :-)